# How to pull transaction reports through FirstData API?

Tags: firstdata

I have been rummaging through the API docs and their website but cannot seem to find any information on pulling transaction reports from the FirstData API. I am interested in getting transaction report data similar to what is found here:
https://firstdata.zendesk.com/entries/407573-First-Data-Global-Gateway-e4-Web-Service-Transaction-Search-and-Reporting-API

I am using the Global Gateway and I cannot seem to access the e4 Web Service. Does anyone have any idea where I can find the information or sample code?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out you need the E4 gateway. You can sign up for a demo gateway here: https://firstdata.zendesk.com/entries/21510561-first-data-global-gateway-e4sm-demo-accounts

That page also has all of the information required for testing including demo credit cards and endpoint URLs. You can see how to request the reporting as identified in the link in the original post above. (https://firstdata.zendesk.com/entries/407573-First-Data-Global-Gateway-e4-Web-Service-Transaction-Search-and-Reporting-API)

This took forever to find, but it appears the Global Gateway itself does not provide this level of functionality.